# Automatically shutdown inactive ipython notebooks

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

Is there any way to configure `ipython notebook` to not keep inactive notebook processes around alive indefinitely? For example automatically shutdown the notebook whenever the client disconnects, or after being idle for `n` minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no config option for that. Feel free to file an [issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/) to request the feature.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution in 2021

Set the following values in `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` or your config file

```
c.MappingKernelManager.cull_busy = False
c.MappingKernelManager.cull_connected = False
c.MappingKernelManager.cull_idle_timeout = 86400
```

where the 86400 means 1 day (= 86400s).

### See also

- https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/2215
- https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/which-is-the-correct-way-to-cull-idle-kernels-and-notebook/8123

Answer (score 1):

This feature was added in release 5.1. See the following issue and pull request

- https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5539
- https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/2215