# stop Jupiter notebook by a cell

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have very complex Jupiter notebooks that I would like to shut it down after it completes running. I wanted to do this like by adding a cell called

```
return None
```

or

```
%Exit notebook
```

But it seems I could not find any way to do this. Could anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70389381/4935162) or [this](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/which-is-the-correct-way-to-cull-idle-kernels-and-notebook/8123/15) or [that](https://groups.google.com/g/jupyter/c/3zAVHofQykg)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To shut down a Jupyter notebook after it has completed running, you can use the ipython magic command '%exit'. This magic command will exit the Jupyter notebook and close the kernel, effectively shutting down the notebook.
So, you can add this cell at the end of your notebook(or where you need it to stop):

```
%exit
```

Alternatively, you can use the exit() function from the built-in sys module to exit the Jupyter notebook, like this:

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

Keep in mind that the %exit magic command and the sys.exit() function will only work if the kernel is still running. If the kernel has already completed executing all of the cells in the notebook, the notebook will already be shut down and these commands will have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

%exit
Alternatively, you can use the exit() function from the built-in sys module to exit the Jupyter notebook, like this:

import sys
sys.exit()